# AWS S3 Permission denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have a link like which is working fine

**https://s3.amazonaws.com/soemthing.com/2015/03/ap04010203260-1.jpg%3Fquality%3D100**

But if i use

**https://s3.amazonaws.com/soemthing.com/2015/03/ap04010203260-1.jpg?quality=100**

it gives me following error

**

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>2BD025CB05F4dd</RequestId>
<HostId>
lUjn2+NH+4crL7GbAbWi8vEiEldkldC2fvbGIcwj29flHiNHLTyTfQLvcU+F+NidruCGKsZbR7MA=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

**

I need to open this link without **url decode**

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: what is the actual filename? I mean, does it have spaces or characters after `.jpg`?

Comment: why are you using the `s3.amazonaws.com` endpoint instead of the website endpoint (like `something.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`)?

Comment: there are two endpoints. one is for https and other is for http .

Comment: It works fine for me (using my own bucket). Could you provide a sample link that actually works? eg: https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/share.jr-class.net/fluffy.jpg?quality=100 (Feel free to create a temporary bucket for this purpose).